# What package do I use to model a material and get the LAMMPS data file as an output?

Tags: software-recommendations, lammps, vmd

VMD has a nanotube builder that I can use to build CNT and then using topotools I am able to produce the data file for LAMMPS. For my specific research I need to create a fake CNT with triangular lattice instead of hegxagonal. I can create that with mathematica but it explodes and I guess it is because I do not have the dihedral and other angle informations.

**My question is if you know of any (preferably free) software that I can use to create my own specific lattice shape nanotube and get the data file as an output?**

Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

First, can you clarify what you mean by "it explodes"? Have you ensured that there are no overlaps in your simulation and that the force-field parameters are correct?

Moltemplate is another <strike>free, open source</strike> powerful program for preparing LAMMPS datafiles. There is an extensive set of tutorials including one on [nanotubes](https://github.com/jewettaij/moltemplate/tree/master/examples/all_atom/force_field_explicit_parameters/nanotube+water#nanotube-water-capillary-system). Moltemplate uses `.LT` files that are basically the pieces that construct the system. Then using `system.lt` file and with different options, you can create a LAMMPS datafile along with other optional input files. My suggestion: Try to read the actually very well-written manual. Start with a few simple examples found in examples folder and then try to find similar examples to your system.